# Show that the exists an unbounded open subset of the complex plane where sinz is bounded

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

$$ \sin z = \frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i} $$

So I think $ \sin z \le 1/2 + 1/2 = 1 $.

But I am not sure how to find an unbounded subset of the complex plane, is it not bounded on the whole

Comment: Which values can the sine function take on the real axis?

Comment: Note that $\sin$ is not a bounded function on the entire complex plane (just to make sure because you wrote $\sin z \leq 1$; this is not true for all complex numbers although it is true if $z$ is real).

Comment: You can not compare complex numbers using inequality in general. Perhaps you meant to write $\lvert \sin z \rvert \leq 1$? This fails for instance when $z = i$, as $\lvert \sin i \rvert = \sinh(1) > 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A = \{ z : |\sin z| < 2 \}$. Then $\sin z$ is obviously bounded on $A$, and $A$ is unbounded (since it contains $\mathbb{R}$) and open (since it is the inverse image of the open set $\{ t < 2 \} \subset \mathbb{R}$ under the continuous function $f(z) = |\sin z|$.)